# Modifying more than one column requires server reboot

Tags: mysql

I have a completely empty table with six columns:

```
| url           | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| column1       | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| column2       | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| column3       | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| column4       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| column5       | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

I can modify one column and it works fine:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY column4 VARCHAR(30);

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

But as soon as I try to modify another column, the cursor just blinks endlessly and nothing happens until I reboot the server and try again. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but you might be running out of disk space to do the ALTER TABLE, if this table is larger than the amount of free disk space.

Comment: I have > 100GB left on the disk and there are no records in the table

Comment: Another possibility is that the table is locked with a metadata lock. Any long-running query or transaction against that table will block ALTER TABLE. Naturally, rebooting will interrupt that long-running query. See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093998/mysql-alter-table-taking-long-in-small-table/59094093#59094093

Comment: Running `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` might help to check what is happening during and other than the `ALTER TABLE` query

Comment: Write here mysql exact version. First step I recommend DB update to last version.

Comment: high possibility is that table could be locked with metadata lock. Please share `show full processlist;` output while running alter query.